# Need to Display the Results of MySQLi num_rows in Separate Table from Array Results

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, echo, mysql-num-rows

I have a page that displays a MySQLi query result array. On this page the data comes to the page correctly but for my `$result['rows']` which is the result of `num_rows` of the array results are showing up for each record and then the array results are being displayed. For example if there are 100 records to the query there is '100' displayed 100 times before the array results. I know it's because I'm using `foreach` but I can't get it work with anything else. I've tried `while`, `for`, and `continue` but nothing works but `foreach` to retrieve the data correctly. What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
            if($results) {
    echo "<table id='test' class='tablesorter' border='2'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='header'># of Records</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

        foreach($_SESSION['results'] as $result) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$result['rows']}</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
            }
            ?>

            <?php
            if($results) {
    echo "<table id='test' class='tablesorter' border='2'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Date Set</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Branch</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Appointment Date</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Employee</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>First Name</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Last Name</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Last Four</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Phone</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>City</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>State</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Zip</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";


            foreach($_SESSION['results'] as $result) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$result['set_date']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['branch']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['appt_date']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['employee']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['fname']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['lname']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['last_four']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['phone']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['city']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['state']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['zip']}</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";            

}else{

    echo "No Records Found";
}
?>
```

Comment: you're storing your mysqli results in a session?

Comment: @trex005 yes, it is stored as a session. Results are correct but the 'num_rows' results is being displayed the amount of times that there records for the query. I want it to show up just once. Want to use something besides 'foreach' but nothing else brings back the query results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
foreach($_SESSION['results'] as $result) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$result['rows']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

to:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$_SESSION['results'][0]['rows']}</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
$cnt = count($_SESSION['results'];
$s = ($cnt == 1) ? '' : 's';
echo "<th class='header'><?php echo $cnt ?> Record<?php echo $s ?></th>";
```

No need to loop on an array just to get how many items are in there - that's what `count()` is for.

Comment: so this would take the place of my 'for' statement? Would this pass the rest of the array results to the 2nd table?

Comment: why shouldn' it? you're not "passing" anything. you're executing two separate loops, all this would do is completely remote the need to have the first loop.